# Postgres pg_dump now stored procedure fails because of boolean

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, boolean

I have a stored procedure that has started to fail for no reason. Well there must be one but I can't find it!

This is the process I have followed a number of times before with no problem.

The source server works fine!

I am doing a pg_dump of the database on source server and imported it onto another server - This is fine I can see all the data and do updates.

Then I run a stored procedure on the imported database that does the following on the database which has 2 identical schema's -

```
For each table in schema1
    Truncate table in schema2
    INSERT  INTO schema2."table" SELECT *  FROM schema1."table" WHERE "Status" in ('A','N');
Next
```

However this gives me an error now when it did not before - 
The error is

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: column "HBA" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Why am I getting this - The only difference between the last time I followed this procedure and this time is that the table in question now has an extra column added to it so the "HBA" boolean column is not the last field. But then why would it work in original database!

I have tried removing all data, dropping and rebuilding table these all fail.
However if I drop column and adding it back in if works - Is there something about Boolean fields that mean they need to be the last field!

Any help greatly apprieciated.

Using Postgres 9.1

Comment: `INSERT  INTO schema2."table" SELECT *  ` Have you tried to avoid the `*` and explicitely name the columns, maybe adding a typecast for the boolean<-->int ?

Comment: Would like to but this is looping through all the table.

I just run the complete set of stored procedures that recreate the second schema. Now the stored procedure works!!

Looking at the database it has rebuilt it with the boolean column as the last column. So this could be the issue.

Comment: there's too much guesswork involved if you don't the show the structures of your source and destination tables at the precise time when it fails.

Comment: seems the columns orders in the schema2 table is not the same as the one from schema1 same name table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here - tables in different schemas were having different column order.

If you do not explicitly specify column list and order in `INSERT INTO table(...)` or use `SELECT *` - you are relying on the column order of the table (and now you see why it is a bad thing).

You were trying to do something like

```
INSERT INTO schema2.table1(id, bool_column, int_column) -- based on the order of columns in schema2.table1
select id, int_column, bool_column -- based on the order of columns in schema1.table1
from schema1.table1;
```

And such query caused cast error because column type missmatch.

Comment: You are right - I found if I rebuilt the tables in schema2 based on schema1 from scratch - i.e. dropping them and recreating them the stored procedure now works.

Comment: I think that the psql dump has changed the structure of the tables as a number of tables INHERIT from parent tables thus the order can not be guaranteed but rebuilding them does. Thanks for your help all.